# How do i make the relation of a drop down field to use the OR logic instead of AND in php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I'm currently trying to edit the relation of the **City** dropdown which you can find on [this page](https://dispensary.tmmbuilds.com/cannabis-dispensary-south-africa/) to use the the OR logic like on the first field **Region**

I have attempted to change the AND to OR through the function.php file like below but this didn't work

```
function filter_florida_location() {

     ob_start();
        
        $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
        if (isset($_POST['region']) && !empty($_POST['region']))
        {  
            $tax_query[] =  array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'region',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    =>  $_POST['region'],
                    //'operator' => 'IN',
                );
        } 
        
        
        if (isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city']))
        {   
            foreach($_POST['city'] as $key => $val){
            $tax_query[] = array('relation' => 'OR');   
            $tax_query[][] =  array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'city',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => array($val),
            );
            }   
        }
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this

```
$tax_query[] = array('relation' => 'OR');
```

to

```
$tax_query['relation'] = 'OR';
```